# Oracle SQL add apostrophes

Tags: sql, oracle, apostrophe

Is there a way to deal with apostrophes/multiples quotes in a SQL oracle string?
I tried with `listagg` but only able to add the commas but not the apostrophes/multiples quotes.
The goal is to add the users in another `SQL Table` -> `IN Operator`

Example:

```
select LISTAGG(username, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY username) "USERNAME" from user
```

Current output: `james, arthur, peter, gina, lehner`

Goal:  `'james', 'arthur', 'peter', 'gina', 'lehner'`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *simplest* solution is to add the apostrophes in the delimiter and add a leading and trailing apostroph

```
 select ''''||listagg(username,q'[', ']') within group (order by username)||'''' as txt from names
```

gives

```
 'ames', 'arthur', 'gina', 'lehner', 'peter'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select LISTAGG(''''||username||'''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY username) "USERNAME" from user
```

Comment: Thx you! for the explanation and support!

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to NOT build a list at all. Since the goal is to "add the users in another SQL Table -> IN, and that list must be built by a select. You are selecting user names in order to construct this list which will need to be de-constructed in the other query. Why not just incorporate the select that builds the list directly into the SQL -> IN. So Select Table ... where column_name in (Select username from user).

Answer (score 2):

You can apply any row-function (such as concatination) on the column before applying a window-function to it:

```
SELECT LISTAGG('''' || username || '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY username) "USERNAME"
FROM   user
```

Comment: Thx you! for the explanation and support!